# Calculating Open ended cone height

Tags: area, solid-geometry

If I have the diameter for both bases of the open-ended cone, and they are 20, and 16. Is there any way I could get the height of that open-ended cone?

Answer (score 2):

No: pick two disks of those diameters and put them as far apart as you like. You can always find a conical frustum which has them as bases.